# Chrome body and html height 100% by default

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Let's say you wanted your content to take up `100%` of the height of the viewport. You used to have to set the height of the `html` and `body` elements to `100%`. This way, you could give direct descendants of the `body` element percentage heights as well, like so:

```
<head>
  <style>
    html, body { height: 100% }
    body { margin: 0; }
    header, footer { height: 10% }
    main { height: 80% }
  <style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>Intro</header>
  <main>The Main Stuff</main>
  <footer>Additional Details</footer>
</body>
```

The `html, body { height: 100% }` declaration is no longer required to set a percentage height on direct descendants in Chrome. However, it's still required in Firefox.

Is this a bug in the latest update to Chrome, which came early February? Or is the `height` now set to `100%` by default?

Just to clarify, I'm not asking about *how* to implement a percentage-based layout. I'm more asking about Chrome's implementation of the `body` and `html` elements' default heights. This could be *very confusing* for novice developers who might come to think that the `html` and `body` don't need a height explicitly defined if they want direct descendants of the `body` to have percentage-based heights.

Comment: It really depends on the browser. Your safest bet, if you must use percentage heights, is to define the height on the parent. Otherwise, a simpler alternative would just be `main { height: 80vh; }` and `header, footer { height: 10vh; }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the code you provided, the `html` and `body` take up 100% of the page height because there's no `doctype` declaration. Most browsers will revert to 'quirks' mode if no `doctype` is provided.

If you add the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), you should find that the body and html elements no longer take up the whole viewport without an explicit height.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say whether there is a bug or not, but in order to ensure that your elements take up 100% of the **viewport** height, you should really use `100vh`:

```
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Percentage-based heights are always relative to the direct parent. As there's no parent of `<html>`, you would expect it to default to a height of 0px. Some browsers may interpret how to handle the parent of `<body>` differently, so it's safest to just use `vh` measurements for the `<body>` tag.

Note that you can use `vh` units on **any** element -- not just `<html>` and `<body>`!

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're using viewport percentage units, you don't need to specify the height on `html` and `body`. You can apply it directly to your content elements (just like using pixel heights).

Comment: Correct, and admittedly my answer wasn't very clear. I've just updated the answer to also mention that :)